# Issue with cart in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

im making a cart for a website, when i have items in the cart im trying to create the option of taking them out from it (deleting).
The thing is that when i press the delete all button it works perfectly fine (localeStorage.clear), however, when i press the X (manually deleting one item) when i refresh the page it shows again and its never being deleted from the localeStorage.
this are the methods i am using:

```js
// this method deletes one item from the cart (not in the LS)
        eliminarProducto(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let producto, productoID;
        if (e.target.classList.contains('borrar-producto')) {
            e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
            producto = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
            productoID = producto.querySelector('a').getAttribute('data-id');
        }
        this.eliminarProductoLocalStorage(productoID);
        this.calcularTotal();
```

```js
 vaciarCarrito(e) { // this method clears the cart (not in LS) 
        e.preventDefault();
        while (listaProductos.firstChild) {
            listaProductos.removeChild(listaProductos.firstChild);
        }
        this.vaciarLocalStorage();

        return false;
    }
```

```js
eliminarProductoLocalStorage(productoID) {// this method deletes the selected item from the LS
        let productosLS;
        //Obtenemos el arreglo de productos
        productosLS = this.obtenerProductosLocalStorage();
        //Comparar el id del producto borrado con LS
        productosLS.forEach(function (productoLS, index) {
            if (productoLS.id === productoID) {
                productosLS.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });

        //Añadimos el arreglo actual al LS
        localStorage.setItem('productos', JSON.stringify(productosLS));
    }
```

```js
vaciarLocalStorage() {// clears the cart (in LS)
        localStorage.clear();
    }
```

[Cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76lvh.png)

Answer (score 0):

maybe the solution is to replace in the function EliminarProductoLocalStorage the last line with localstorage.removeItem()? Because i do not understand why you set an item in a function where you want to delete it from localstorage.